# Converting Value To String In For Loop In GoLang

Tags: string, go

In GoLang I am looping through my form data like this,

```
for key, values := range r.Form {   // range over map
    for _, value := range values {    // range over []string
        fmt.Println(key, value)
    }
}
```

I can print the data out to the terminal like this but I need this data to be a string so I can access it from outside of the for loop.

How can I Put this in a variable that I can call outside of the for loop when the loop is finished?

My goal here is to build a url by joining these three strings

```
var SearchUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query="
var MovieSearch []string = r.Form["GetSearchKey"]   
var apiKey = "&api_key=e2a"
UrlBuild := []string {SearchUrl, MovieSearch, apiKey}
fmt.Println(UrlBuild)
```

I get this error

```
/main.go:71: cannot use MovieSearch (type []string) 
as type string in array or slice literal
```

`MovieSearch` is coming from the input form. It is the search keywords.

Once I have one string I can pass this to a function that makes the api call.

The full function

```
func searchHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  display(w, "search", &Page{Title: "Search"})
   fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) 
        r.ParseForm()
        fmt.Println("GetSearchKey:", r.Form["GetSearchKey"])

for key, values := range r.Form {   // range over map
for _, value := range values {    // range over []string
    fmt.Println(key, value)

  }
}

var SearchUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query="
 var MovieSearch []string = r.Form["GetSearchKey"]   
var apiKey = "&api_key=ewrfwrfwrcwerc"
UrlBuild := []string {SearchUrl, MovieSearch, apiKey}
fmt.Println(UrlBuild)

fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(r.Form["GetSearchKey"] ))
}
```

The error comes from this line,

```
UrlBuild := []string {SearchUrl, MovieSearch, apiKey}
```

Comment: What's wrong with having the data in the map?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Add an example.

Comment: "How can I Put this in a variable that I can call outside of the for loop" - maybe by storing it in a variable that you defined outside of the loop?

Comment: I am trying to convert it to a string so I can build a url out of it. Ill edit right now.

Comment: Working through the Tour of Go twice might be well spent 4 hours.

Comment: What do you get when you range over the MovieSearch?  I would think you would need to create the UrlBuild slice with SearchUrl, append the values from MovieSearch, and then append the api key.

Comment: Yes what you said is sounds ideal. I am just trying to make things work the best I know how. What I don't understand is that when I use reflect and check the type it is a string.. so why can I not just concatenate it? If you believe there is a better way would you please show me? Also I really truly would like to understand why I can concatenate the form data when it is indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a slice within a slice.

```
func ArrayToString(array []string) string {
    str := strings.Join(array, "")
    return str

}
UrlBuild := []string {SearchUrl, ArrayToString(MovieSearch), apiKey}
fmt.Println(UrlBuild) 
UrlBuildString := ArrayToString(UrlBuild)
```

OR

```
UrlBuildString := ArrayToString([]string{SearchUrl, ArrayToString(MovieSearch), apiKey}
```

_________________FULL_______________

```
func ArrayToString(array []string) string {
    str := strings.Join(array, "")
    return str

}
func searchHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  display(w, "search", &Page{Title: "Search"})
   fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) 
        r.ParseForm()
        fmt.Println("GetSearchKey:", r.Form["GetSearchKey"])

for key, values := range r.Form {   // range over map
for _, value := range values {    // range over []string
    fmt.Println(key, value)

  }
}

var SearchUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query="
 var MovieSearch []string = r.Form["GetSearchKey"]   
var apiKey = "&api_key=ewrfwrfwrcwerc"
UrlBuild := []string {SearchUrl, ArrayToString(MovieSearch), apiKey}
fmt.Println(UrlBuild)
OUTPUT_STRING := ArrayToString(UrlBuild)
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for trying to help me out. Would you mind elaborating a little on this.

Comment: Yeah... I just through this out there. It turns an array into a string by joining it

Comment: Cool thanks man, so I have 2 string and 1 input value from a form. the value from the form says it is a string when I check it with reflect. But I guess its an string array maybe and that's what is killing me? if so I am not even sure how I would use that function to concatenate it all. If you look at my question and see these tree vars SearchUrl MovieSearch and apiKey would you mind updating your answer with how to bring all those together in to one string var so I can call that var in another function.

Comment: Ahh I get it. One sec

Comment: Wait, what does, `MovieSearch` look like

Comment: Wuno, if your sure they are all strings, you would just use myString := SearchUrl + MovieSearch + apiKey to get a string.  If MovieSearch is an array of strings, you could use XXXs function like this myString := SearchUrl + ArrayToString(MovieSearch) + apiKey

Comment: Exactly thats my point. its coming from a form. And when i try and do what you just suggested it gives me the error I posted in my question. When I use reflection I get this as the type []string and when I print it to the terminal it looks like this [hahahahahahah]

Comment: Did you try converting it with the function?

Comment: I didnt understand how. I am going to edit my question and show you the code i have.

Comment: The error references line 71.  What is the actual code on that line?  Would make it easier to see what is going on then.

Comment: Ok I updated at the bottom I show you exactly the error and the whole function I am writing. And Wade... I really really appreciate you.

Comment: Haha right on man. Bro my whole app is decent work. I just do not understand what this specific issue is. I do not understand why that is such blasphemy that warrants down votes. But either way I just want to understand.

Comment: Ok. Your problem is you are trying to create a slice(list in golang), with slice within it. This is illegal in golang the way you are doing it. So, you need to convert all the items in the slice to a string, to make it legal. My function `ArrayToString` does this. Now, you have a slice of everything. Convert **THAT** to a string, and voila!

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much for all your help! You both are great. Thanks a ton. So at the end I think I need to understand what slice is and does better.  Is that pretty much it?

Comment: Yes, you need to read http://www.dotnetperls.com/slice-go and http://openmymind.net/The-Minimum-You-Need-To-Know-About-Arrays-And-Slices-In-Go/

Comment: Hey man the whole app works now thanks to you. My only issue is that if there is multiple words in the search field it ends up removing the +between them that is needed for the url. so if I search bad santa the url ends up not placing the + between bad+santa. To fix this should I just be able to add the + after each value in the ArrayToString function?

Answer (score 1):

This problem doesn't seem so bad, though I may be misunderstanding the question. There are many ways to build up these strings.

Consider the following approach using concatenation (slow):

```
s := []string{}
for key, values := range r.Form {   // range over map
    for _, value := range values {    // range over []string
        s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s", key, value))
    }
}
data := strings.Join(s, ";")
```

More examples of concat are seen here: http://herman.asia/efficient-string-concatenation-in-go

Comment: But since I am building a url does it make sense to do it like I am attempting? I just edited my question.